# Android Virtual Device frozen whilst loading

Tags: android-emulator, virtualization

I have just started developing for android after a 4 year break, I see that the Android developer site now has an integrated package with everything included, in a single zip, to streamline setting up. I have downloaded and extracted the zip file and begun going through the tutorial.

However, when creating a virtual machine, it just hangs. I have followed the suggestions in this post: [I can't get any of the Android Virtual Devices started](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62576/i-cant-get-any-of-the-android-virtual-devices-started)

My machine has 16GB RAM and an AMD Phenom 2 6-Core processor. I have set the RAM to 768MB for the VM and even after 15 minutes it is just frozen.

The Console shows some details of the VM I have created, but does not progress much. Any suggestions on how to get a working VM?

Comment: Have you tried using a prebuilt AVD definition like a Nexus device?

Comment: Yes, attempted Nexus 4 and 5. They did not load, then attempted building one with smaller requirements, still no luck.

Comment: Try changing the CPU to x86?

Answer (score 0):

Try androidx86 http://www.android-x86.org/download, just download the iso and create a new virtual machine, you only need about 1gb of ram.

Comment: I'm fairly certain his computer is more than capable of virtualizing a device. This is a good option as well *if* it works for development purposes.